# Separar elementos de una lista identificando un conjunto de letras

Tags: python

en primer lugar disculparme por el título de la pregunta, que no es nada aclaratorio.

Tengo una lista con los nombre de varios archivos de una carpeta, del tipo: archivo1_A1, archivo1_A2, archivo2_A1, archvio2_A2, ...

¿Cómo puedo crear dos listas de esta lista, una conteniendo todos los elementos terminados con _A1 y otra con todos los _A2?

Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si presuponemos que lo que tienes es una lista de cadenas de esta forma:

```
nombres = ['archivo1_A1', 'archivo1_A2', 'archivo2_A1', 'archvio2_A2']
```

Lo más simple es usar `str.endswith`:

```
lista_A1 = [nombre for nombre in nombres if nombre.endswith('_A1')] 
lista_A2 = [nombre for nombre in nombres if nombre.endswith('_A2')]
```

Si todos tus archivos terminan en '_A1' o '_A2' se podría hacer en un solo `for`.

Si necesitaras algo más complejo porque trabajaras con nombres de archivos con más complejidad, por ejemplo, con extensión ('archivo1_A1.py', 'archivo1_A1.exe', etc) lo mejor sería usar expresiones regulares.

Answer (score 2):

Seguramente hay formas mejores, por lo pronto se me ocurre es usar la comprensión de listas, una técnica muy poderosa del lenguaje que permite transformar/filtrar cualquier lista de manera rápida:

```
lista = [ "archivo1_A1",
          "archivo1_A2", 
          "archivo2_A1", 
          "archvio2_A2"
]

a1 = [a for a in lista if a[-2:] == "A1" ]
a2 = [a for a in lista if a[-2:] == "A2" ]
print("Archivos A1 = {}".format(a1))
print("Archivos A2 = {}".format(a2))
```

Y la salida:

```
Archivos A1 = ['archivo1_A1', 'archivo2_A1']
Archivos A2 = ['archivo1_A2', 'archvio2_A2']
```

La estructura:

```
[a for a in lista if a[-2:] == "A1" ]
```

Lo que dice es:

- Generame una lista `[]`
- con cada uno de los elemento `a` de la lista original `a for a in lista`
- Y que además tengan la condición que los últimos 2 caracteres sean `A1` (`if a[-2:] == "A1"`)